# How can i change the login component so that it uses a new field in the registration form instead the username or email (i.e account number)?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

So basically, the title. How can i change the login component so that it uses a new field in the registration form instead the username or email, my client wants to use an account number that the users type in the registration form. So the login would be Account Number/password.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If that was so simple - there were no wordpress security vulnerabilities. Ideal way to solve your peoblem: copy any existing code from github or any other sources, after testing, and modifying, ask what you can not implement

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, the best way to post an answer is to add more description to the question and also some steps you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Wp membership plugin" and in registration page username field, you can customize and add new field like Account No.